# Алгоритм для онлайн записи

Tags: php, запрос, mysql

Необходимо для сайта одной стоматологической клиники сделать онлайн запись. Отправить данные в БД я смогу, а как сделать:

1. Чтобы выбранные дата и число становились недоступными для других
2. К каждой дате привязывать новую табличку с временем

Comment: Ничего не понял.

Comment: Вы случаем метками не ошиблись? Чем обробатывать собрались, php?

Comment: Кто они эти другие ?

Comment: Став членом сообщества ХэшКод - стань членом сообщества Экстрасенсов (с)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При показе формы не показываем или не даем выбирать те даты, которые уже занесены в БД.

Собственно вот и весь ответ на вопрос.

но про пункт 2 - это не к нам, мы не понимашки.

Comment: 2й пункт это наверное часы приёма. Типа помечать что "сеанс" с 10:00 по 11:00 занят :)

`*снимает телепатический шлем*`

Comment: @shurik дай шлем погонять на денек ;)

Comment: Шурик, правильно!
У каждой даты есть часы приема. 
На каждый день создавать отдельную БД? Или есть другие варианты?
И есть ли уже готовые может какие-нибудь скрипты?